# Overall correlation in ggpairs with colour grouping?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

This code produces a nice pairs plot that has a correlation read-out on the middle right:

```
library(GGally)
ggpairs(esoph[,c(1,4,5)], colour='agegp')
```

You can get just the correlation square with:

```
ggally_cor(data=esoph[,c(1,4,5)],
           mapping=aes(x=ncases, y=ncontrols, colour='agegp'))
```

The square contains a correlation per group. Is there any way to get the correlation for the over-all data set to appear as well? If you don't use `colour=...` then you get it, but then you don't get the per-group correlations.

Comment: feature request submitted: https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/issues/8

Comment: Any chance you could expand this out a bit and show the example plot and some more detail?

Comment: andy, check the link in my comment. this has been fixed. I think I probably should just delete this question...

Comment: My concern was more that it wasn't a very self contained question and I had no idea what you were asking! But, if you've solved it pending a new code update, maybe leave it and let someone answer this when the new version gets released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now verify that this works with `GGally_0.4.4` with `R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)` on 
`Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)`

```
library(GGally)
ggally_cor(data=esoph[,c(1,4,5)],
       mapping=aes(x=ncases, y=ncontrols, colour='agegp'))
```

See that the overall correllation appears at the top and is consistent with the number I get from this command:

```
ggally_cor(data=esoph[,c(1,4,5)],
       mapping=aes(x=ncases, y=ncontrols))
```

[image]